# Remove a pattern in all strings in a list

Tags: python

For example, if I have a list of strings

```
alist=['a_name1_1', 'a_name1_2', 'a_name1_3']
```

How do I get this:

```
alist_changed = ['a_n1_1', 'a_n1_2', 'a_n1_3']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alist_changed = [s.replace("ame", "") for s in alist]`

Comment: Yes, that's a fair point. As far as I can tell, it's something of a contrived example anyway, however...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something that actually needs to be "pattern" based then you can use python's re module and sub the regular expression pattern for what you want.

```
import re


alist=['a_name1_1', 'a_name1_2', 'a_name1_3']
alist_changed = []

pattern = r'_\w*_'

for x in alist:
    y = re.sub(pattern, '_n1_', x, 1)
    #print(y)
    alist_changed.append(y)


print(alist_changed)
```

Comment: I think using regular expression is a more general way to do it. Thanks a lot for the idea! But since I am only dealing with something simple, i.e. shorten the name of strings, ResMar's answer is sufficient. Thanks!